# Is there a way to run Specflow scenarios in desired order (C# Selenium)?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I'm trying to run multiple Specflow tests in the Test Explorer, but the challenge is I'm unable to run them in the desired order.

ex - I have 3 scenarios in my feature files:

- Login positive
- Login negative
- registration positive

Currently, they run in random order. I want them to always run in the above order. How can I configure my feature files to make it possible?

Comment: why do you want them to run in order

Comment: Agree with the above comment. Best practice with unit tests and even integration / web-ui tests is that a test should be self-contained and be capable of running regardless of external factors such as test ordering. In short - there should be no inter-test dependencies.

Comment: The scenario is such that the complete registration process happens in 4 steps i.e 4 different screens and thus I wanted to have each step as a different test primarily because they are different screens.

Answer (score 7):

For NUnit: Tests inside a scenario run in alphabetical order, so if you want to run them in specific order just rename scenarios like

```
Scenario: 1 Login positive
Scenario: 2 Login negative
Scenario: 3 Registration positive
```

For other frameworks look here: https://www.ontestautomation.com/running-your-tests-in-a-specific-order/

Answer (score 3):

I also think it is so annoying if the tests order in the feature files different than the text explorer. So here is my solution to that.

```
Scenario: 01) Create test data
    Given ...
    When ...
    Then ...
    
Scenario: 02) Modify data
    Given ...
    When ...
    Then ...

Scenario: 03) Remove modified data
    Given ...
    When ...
    Then ...
```

[Source](https://www.ontestautomation.com/running-your-tests-in-a-specific-order/)